# Are cp -r and cp -R the same?

Tags: command-line, cp

A tutorial shows cp -r http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex10.html

but

http://ss64.com/osx/ only shows -R.

Answer (score 4):

The only option [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) defines is `-R`.  Some implementations of `cp`, most notably the one by GNU, provides `-r` (as well as `--recursive`) as an alias.  The author of the tutorial you’re reading is probably using some GNU system, and used `-r`, but you should be absolutely fine using `-R` yourself; and since it is more portable, I would actually recommend getting used to `-R` rather than its synonyms.

Comment: In fact it's arguably better to get into the habit of using `-R` since that will work on any POSIX system.

Comment: Agreed, I was going to say so.  Did I not say so?  I’ll add it.

Comment: I very much like your answers.  I in fact have found http://ss64.com/osx/ much better than http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/.  Is this reasonable to say relating to the proper use of the CLI?

Comment: @MariaS. It’s been a long time since I’ve been helping anyone use the command line, so I can’t recommend any reference.  If you’re on Mac OS X, it makes sense to use a document that’s targeting Mac OS rather than GNU/Linux, at least as a first step.  Ideally, you should also be learning about the POSIX standard.  If you’re ready to spend a few dollars / euros / etc., there are some very good publishers that make small reference books: Addison-Wesley, O’Reilly, The Pragmatic Programmers.

Comment: Ok.  Many thanks for the info and also book info.